# Command to show the content of biggest strings and char arrays on Java 6. How?

Tags: java, hibernate, memory, heap-memory

I'm trying to find a way to return the content of the biggest `String` and `char[]` in the Java Heap, using some java tool for that. I'm using Java 6.

I'm working in an application with some memory issues. Most of the problem is from the String and Char arrays created for the queries generated by JPA Hibernate (version 3.3.0).

I can use `jmap` tool to show the high consume of memory:

```
jmap -histo:live <PID_OF_JAVA_PROCESS> | head -n 20
```

And print something like that (the first one is `char[]`):

```
num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:       3286152     1412140072  [C
   2:      10198187      239513896  [Ljava.lang.String;
   3:       3937983      126015456  java.lang.String
   4:        662242       47550936  [[Ljava.lang.String;
```

I can see the content of the internal char arrays and Strings using Eclipse Memory Analyzer, one by one. But this is not productive.

I would like to have this information more easy, using some java tool to get the all information on this Strings and char arrays and saved in some text file.

With this information, I can see the whole scenario and priorize the queries that are more problematic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JVisualVM, it's easy. Run your program then launch JVisualVM.
Then in the process browser of JVisualVM, identify your Java process and do a right click and select "Head Dump", it will create a dump of the HEAP used by your program.

Enter in the generated Head node in the process browser, then click in the "classes" option, you will have classes.

Search the char[] class name and double click on it and you will find the info you search (all instances of char[] in your HEAP) in the instances table. You can sort all the tables.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I can't find a way with JvisualVM to copy the whole `value` of the char array. I can only see each char individually on array or the beginning of the whole information (the rest appear as `<truncated>`). And I don't find a way with JvisualVM to copy the content of all char arrays and strings.